# Why Regular Expression in CakePHP ( must CakePHP )

Tags: php, cakephp

Why does this code run differently in CakePHP vs. a normal PHP file?

```
<?php
$data = "   One


Two

Three



Four";
$data = trim($data);
$data = preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n", $data);
$data = explode("\n",$data);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

When I run this code in a normal PHP file, I get

```
array
  0 => string 'One' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Two' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Three' (length=5)
  3 => string 'Four' (length=4)
```

but if I run it from a Cake controller I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => two
    [4] => 
    [5] => three
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => four
)
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Are you getting an error? Is it blank? Is your toilet backing up?

Comment: Are you using exactly the same file?

Comment: Is it at least the same code (especially the same line break sequences)?

Comment: i only copy paste code from this file to other file. But 2 result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in Cake that would interfere with the behavior of native PHP functions.  If you post the exact code you're using in Cake, including the action method definition, people will be better able to help you.  My guess if you're doing something like this

```
public function myaction()
{
    $data = "   One


    Two

    Three



    Four";
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n", $data);
    $data = explode("\n",$data);
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Which means \n is never repeated more than once (there's additional whitespace after the \n.  The bigger problem you're looking at is your regular expression isn't doing what you think it should when you run the code in Cake.  Figure out why that is and you'll solve your problem. The following regular expression may prove more robust

```
$data = preg_replace("/[\r\n]\s{0,}/", "\n", $data);
```

Comment: i only copy paste code from this file to other file. But 2 result

Comment: @meotim Is the code *left aligned in the first column*, or is it indented, i.e. are there **tabs** or **spaces** before the 'Two' and 'Three'?

Comment: @meotim If the text is indented, the indention is part of the text: `   One\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\tTwo\n\t\t\n\t\tThree...`, instead of just `   One\n\n\nTwo\n\nThree...`.

Comment: no, i only type enter while test, or only type enter in textarea,
text is indented beacause i test trim($data)

Comment: @meotim Can you copy your Cake test code into your question as well?

Comment: I code in file http://localhost/test.php is work => i copy it in controller cakePHP but it dont same result . Alan Storm 's code work in 2 file ,

Comment: Trim only removes white space from the star and end of a string, not each line. If the 2nd regular expression worked for you, that means there was additional white space at the start of each line